# Excel bug handling dates in Text files using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

So I upload Excel file then save it as Text file but I have problem with date format.

My excel the date format is dd/MM/yyyy but when I save it as Text File its format is MM/dd/yyyy

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop



Dim FileName As String = &quot;C:\myExcelData.txt&quot;
Dim xl As New Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\myExcel.xlsx")

Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
xlSheet.SaveAs(FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlTextWindows)
xlBook.Close()
```

In myExcel.xlsx    Date is 31/01/2014

In myExcelData.txt Date is 1/31/2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add last argument [`Local:=True`](http://www.google.ru/url?q=http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas.aspx&sa=U&ei=53JbU9fsMKOH4gTz7oBQ&ved=0CB0QFjAA&sig2=OHg9uagB0a0KnlRDE1FwYw&usg=AFQjCNGpixFUjJKHDUccGkLzZJP4LFCinw):

```
xlSheet.SaveAs(Filename:=FileName, FileFormat:=Excel.XlFileFormat.xlTextWindows,Local:=True)
```

Comment: I set it to true but still the date is saved as before. How to set the local settings?

Comment: Try to change `date order`. See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840213(v=office.15).aspx or look into [CultureInfo](http://www.google.ru/url?q=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.globalization.cultureinfo&sa=U&ei=inZbU-zbIMa74ASU_YFQ&ved=0CB0QFjAA&sig2=3R42R0rZ25xesvz0b9LB4w&usg=AFQjCNG6XpXGkxq45JIo9zsu8JgB0XnufQ)

Comment: Where do I set the xlDateOrder?

Comment: add something like this before saving workbook: `xl.International(..)...`